# How to sort this XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is the XML that I am trying to sort:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Proposal>
  <MobileKey>test string</MobileKey>
  <RevisionNumber>9</RevisionNumber>
  <CreationDate>2014-04-30T13:21:00</CreationDate>
  <ProposalDueDate>test string</ProposalDueDate>
  <ProposalJobs>
    <ProposalID>56</ProposalID>
    <ProposalRevision>9</ProposalRevision>
    <ProposalJobNumber>9</ProposalJobNumber>
    <ServiceLine>test string</ServiceLine>
    <SubServiceLine>test string</SubServiceLine>
  </ProposalJobs>
  <ProposalJobs>
    <ProposalID>42</ProposalID>
    <ProposalRevision>9</ProposalRevision>
    <ProposalJobNumber>9</ProposalJobNumber>
    <ServiceLine>test string</ServiceLine>
    <SubServiceLine>test string</SubServiceLine>
  </ProposalJobs>
  <ProposalJobs>
    <ProposalID>21</ProposalID>
    <ProposalRevision>9</ProposalRevision>
    <ProposalJobNumber>9</ProposalJobNumber>
    <ServiceLine>test string</ServiceLine>
    <SubServiceLine>test string</SubServiceLine>
  </ProposalJobs>
</Proposal>
```

The output should be (sorted on ProposalID):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Proposal>
  <MobileKey>test string</MobileKey>
  <RevisionNumber>9</RevisionNumber>
  <CreationDate>2014-04-30T13:21:00</CreationDate>
  <ProposalDueDate>test string</ProposalDueDate>
  <ProposalJobs>
    <ProposalID>21</ProposalID>
    <ProposalRevision>9</ProposalRevision>
    <ProposalJobNumber>9</ProposalJobNumber>
    <ServiceLine>test string</ServiceLine>
    <SubServiceLine>test string</SubServiceLine>
  </ProposalJobs>
  <ProposalJobs>
    <ProposalID>42</ProposalID>
    <ProposalRevision>9</ProposalRevision>
    <ProposalJobNumber>9</ProposalJobNumber>
    <ServiceLine>test string</ServiceLine>
    <SubServiceLine>test string</SubServiceLine>
  </ProposalJobs>
  <ProposalJobs>
    <ProposalID>56</ProposalID>
    <ProposalRevision>9</ProposalRevision>
    <ProposalJobNumber>9</ProposalJobNumber>
    <ServiceLine>test string</ServiceLine>
    <SubServiceLine>test string</SubServiceLine>
  </ProposalJobs>
</Proposal>
```

I have used the following XSLT. It does the sorting correctly but deletes all the child elements of `Proposal` except the `ProposalJobs` nodes. Please help me out here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Proposal">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ProposalJobs">
        <xsl:sort select="ProposalID"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ProposalJobs">
    <xsl:sort select="ProposalID"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*">
    <xsl:sort select="ProposalID"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

---

Alternatively, add this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::ProposalJobs)]"/>
```

just before:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ProposalJobs">
    <xsl:sort select="ProposalID"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

---

Not related to your question, but you should change this:

```
<xsl:sort select="ProposalID"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:sort select="ProposalID" data-type="number"/>
```

Otherwise ProposalID #101 will come before #21.

---

### Edit:

To preserve the order of internal "blocks", use:

```
<xsl:template match="Proposal">   
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(preceding-sibling::ProposalJobs)]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ProposalJobs">
            <xsl:sort select="ProposalID" data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[preceding-sibling::ProposalJobs]"/>
    </xsl:copy>  
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This fails if I have any more elements after `ProposalJobs` elements in the above XML. Why? Fails meaning that it does not keep the elements in original sequence in which they appear in XML.

Comment: @Mayank Does it really matter? If yes, please edit your question and post an example that includes such elements.

Comment: You are right. It doesn't really matter. I was just wondering if it can be done. I am accepting your answer for the additional detail and insights it provides. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. I've tested and works fine.

```
<xsl:template match="Proposal">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::ProposalJobs)]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ProposalJobs">
        <xsl:sort select="ProposalID"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you also please explain what the not(self::..) means?

Comment: @Mayank `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::ProposalJobs)]" />` instructcs the XSLT processor to find a template rule for all attribute nodes and all other nodes, except for element nodes that are called "ProposalJobs"

Comment: This fails if I have any more elements after `ProposalJobs` elements in the above XML. Why?

Comment: Fails meaning that it just skips the elements after `ProposalJobs` or does not keep the elements in original sequence in which they appear in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Proposal">   
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::ProposalJobs)]|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ProposalJobs">
        <xsl:sort select="ProposalID"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>   

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```